# Graph API Messages endpoint, what is the filter to get read/unread flag

Tags: graph, office365api

Using this endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/?$top=50&$count=true&$select=receivedDateTime,Id,Sender,Subject,Body

The endpoint works well (have skipped setting Bearer Authorization), but I need to display unread emails darker but can't seem to find the right filter for it.

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error, figured it out.  This is the endpoint with an additional filter

Using this endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/?$top=50&$count=true&$select=receivedDateTime,Id,Sender,Subject,Body,isRead